# How would I get my code to only print the results I search for

Tags: java

I have the following code that is very rough but it's a start for what Ive been asked to accomplish.  My question relates to the list that is generated.  It currently lists all the files on the server and tags the PMR data as mentioned in the code.  Is there something I can change so that the results generated only list the matching data instead of tagging it?

```
import java.io.File;

public class FilePmrDetector {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    listFiles(new File("/"));
}

public static void listFiles(File file) {
    if (file == null || isBlackListed(file)) {
        return;
    }

    doSomeActionOnFile(file);

    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        File[] fs = file.listFiles();

        if (fs != null) {
            for (File f : fs) {
                listFiles(f);
            }
        }
    }
    }

   }

    return false;
   }

  public static void doSomeActionOnFile(File file) {
    String msg = file.getAbsolutePath();

    if (isAPmr(file)) {
        msg += "               ----------PMR-----------";
    }

    System.out.println(msg);
  }

  public static boolean isAPmr(File file) {
    if (file != null) {
        String name = file.getAbsolutePath();
        return name.matches("^.*(\\d{5},[a-zA-z0-9]{3},\\d{3}).*$");
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be runable and it only prints `if (isAPmr(file))`

```
import java.io.File;

public class FilePmrDetector {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    listFiles(new File("/"));
  }

  public static void listFiles(File file) {
    if (file == null) {
      return;
    }

    doSomeActionOnFile(file);

    if (file.isDirectory()) {
      File[] fs = file.listFiles();

      if (fs != null) {
        for (File f : fs) {
          listFiles(f);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static void doSomeActionOnFile(File file) {
    String fileName = file.getAbsolutePath();
    String printOut = "";

    if (isAPmr(file)) {
      printOut = printOut + fileName;
    }
    if (printOut != "") {
      System.out.println(printOut);
    }
  }

  public static boolean isAPmr(File file) {
    if (file != null) {
      String name = file.getAbsolutePath();
      return name.matches("^.*(\\d{5},[a-zA-z0-9]{3},\\d{3}).*$");          
      // I tested with: return name.contains(".exe");
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

---

Edit:

---

This `doSomeActionOnFile(File file)` method is better because it is not overcomplicated like the other.

```
  public static void doSomeActionOnFile(File file) {
    if (isAPmr(file)) {
      System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
  }
```

Comment: any chance you could show me what to edit in the script to make it scan all the partitions of a server?   Right now if I run the above, it will show me all the results from the C:.  the bulk of the Windows machines i'll run it on have a C: a D: and a E: that would all have files that match the search.  I will also run it on linux servers too so I was hoping there might be a line or two that could be changed to have it scan against all mounted drives?